# how to use jquery index()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find the index of the following element

```
<ol id="parent">
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a class="index_of_this"></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
</ol>
```

But I keep getting -1

```
$('#parent a.index_of_this')
```

thank you for your help

Comment: I should add that I am trying to get the index of the li element obviously not the a element.

Answer (score 1):

To get an index of `1`, do this:

```
$("a.index_of_this").parent().index();​ //1
//or this...
$("#parent").children(":has(.index_of_this)").index(); //1
```

[You can play with it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753939/how-to-use-jquery-index)

Answer (score 0):

this worked!!

```
$('#parent li:has(a.index_of_this)').index()
```